# cors trouble calling web service from jquery

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, apache-axis, cors

I've created a web service with axis2 and I've deployed in apache tomcat 7 with eclipse.

This is the class which I converted in a web service. It's just an echo:

```
package test.org;
public class TestWS {
    public String echo(String s){
        return ("You typed: " + s);
    }
}
```

If I try this web service from Eclipse, adding the wsdl in Web Services Explorer it works perfectly, but the problem comes when I try to consume this ws from jquery.
I can access without any problem to the wsdl, which is located at:   `http://localhost:8080/SimpleWS/services/TestWS?wsdl`

But, when I try this code, the following error happen: XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8080/SimpleWS/services/TestWS`. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've been reading about CORS and about including in the server side some code like this:Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, but since I've deployed my ws directly with eclipse I don't know how to do this and I'm not sure if this is my problem.

Thank you in advance!!

Here is my code:

```
<h3>Web service example</h3>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function callWS() {
    var soapmessage = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' " +
                                    "xmlns:q0='http://org.test' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" +
                                    "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>";
                      soapmessage += "<soapenv:Body>";
                      soapmessage += "<q0:echo>";
                      soapmessage += "<q0:s>HELLO</q0:s>";
                      soapmessage += "</q0:echo>";
                      soapmessage += "</soapenv:Body>";
                      soapmessage += "</soapenv:Envelope>";
                      alert(soapmessage);
                      $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: 'http://localhost:8080/SimpleWS/services/TestWS',
                          data: soapmessage,
                          contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
                          dataType: "xml",
                          success: function (data) {
                             alert(data);
                          },
                          error: function (data) {
                              alert("error" + data.d);
                          }
                     });
                     alert("Form Submitted");
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="button" onclick="callWS()" value="execute" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an easier way to do the same.

The function might be:

```
function callWS() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/SimpleWS/services/TestWS/echo", 
        type: "POST",
        data: { s : "HELLO" }, 
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert($(data).find("return").text());
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

In the URL is added the name of operation to call. The data is a map with the key-value pair for each argument.

The name of operation and the names of keys must match with WSDL document, including the names of each element in the response. You can see the schema file with:

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleWS/services/TestWS?xsd
```

This gives something like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ... >
  <xs:element name="echo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="s" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="echoResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This file lists two main types (for this example), the request with `s` element, and the response with `return` element.

The WSDL show the operations's names.

```
<wsdl:binding name="TestWSHttpBinding" type="ns:TestWSPortType">
  <http:binding verb="POST"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="echo">
    <http:operation location="echo"/>
    <wsdl:input>
      <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
      <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

See also:

- [HTTP GET & POST Binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_http)
- [Accessing the Web service with GET, POST, and SOAP bindings](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.ii.doc/ad/ciiacws1.htm)

#### About Origin `null` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Most probably that you're making the request with `XMLHttpRequest` using a local file. e.g. from:

```
file:///C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/index.html
```

The domain, protocol and port not are the same like the URL of WebService. Wikipedia says about that in [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> The term "origin" is defined using the domain name, application layer protocol, and (in most browsers) port number of the HTML document running the script. Two resources are considered to be of the same origin if and only if all these values are exactly the same.

Try with a file in the *same origin*, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleWS/index.jsp
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.I did exactly what you told me but I still have same problem.
Chrome console says: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/SimpleWS/services/TestWS/echo. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
And I get an alert with an error.
I think it has to be something with the domains...What could it be?